# Laravel Multiple Table Subquery

Tags: laravel, eloquent, subquery, laravel-6, eloquent-relationship

I'm using Laravel 6.0
I have 4 different tables.

Tables:

> **post_category**

| id | relation_post_id | post_type | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

> **photo_post**

| id | title | image | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

> **text_post**

| id | title | content | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

> **video_post**

| id | title | video_source_url | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

I'd like to list posts in two date ranges from the post_category table. For example

```
PostCategory::whereBetween('created_at',[$from, $to])->get();
```

The result should be:

Result

> https://i.ibb.co/y53PmJ9/image.png

How can I do that?

Models:
PostCategory

```
class PostCategory extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;
protected $table = 'post_category';
public $timestamps = true;

protected $fillable = [
    'relation_post_id',
    'post_type', // 1: text, 2: photo, 3: video
    'category_id',


];

public function text()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TextPost','relation_post_id','id');
}
public function photo()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\PhotoPost','relation_post_id','id');
}
public function video()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\VideoPost','relation_post_id','id');
}}
```

TextPost

```
class TextPost extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;
protected $table = 'text_post';
public $timestamps = true;

protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'content',
];
}
```

PhotoPost

```
class PhotoPost extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;
protected $table = 'photo_post';
public $timestamps = true;

protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'image',

];
}
```

Video Post

```
class VideoPost extends Model
{
use SoftDeletes;
protected $table = 'video_post';
public $timestamps = true;

protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'video_source_url',

];
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code of your for Eloquent models you have so far?

Comment: ok, i updated questions, thank you

Comment: Ah, okay. Pretty basic. The way you have it, will make it cumbersome to have an array of all these models. You'd have to filter them separately and then merge them. Consider using polymorphic relationships as mentioned below since your example seems almost predestined for that case and would make your programming life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's possible. But since we just know your database design but not your codebase, it's hard to say. Intuitively I'd go with a [polymorphic relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships).